# changing input css by comparing input Name

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
error: function (xhr) {
 $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function(key) {
    console.log(xhr.responseJSON.errors);
     return key<2;
});
},
```

Above function returns me the following result:

[image]

and I have input fields with same name civil_no efirst and esecond

I want to turn inputs border red if field name is in json response.

I tried something like below but it is not working.

```
    error: function (xhr) {

    var arr = [ "efirst", "esecond", "civil_no"];

$.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function(key,value,i) {

if(xhr.responseJSON.errors=arr[i]){

     $( "input[name=" arr[i]]).removeClass('border border-dark');
     $( "input[name=" arr[i] ).addClass('errorClass');

     return key<1;
}
 });
    },
```

> console.log(key); //returns efirst,esecond,civil_no

Comment: `xhr.responseJSON.errors=arr[i]` what are you comparing? An array compare with a string?

Comment: arr is array, and xhr.responseJSON.errors has efirst,esecond etc names, for example,i want to compare if efirst of response = efirst of array

Comment: please check updated

Comment: `i` is undefined in the `each` callback....  copied from docs `$.each( obj, function( key, value )` . There is no third argument. Your `if` is trying to compare a whole object to something else which can't ever work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at this is loop over your array of field names and see if that property exists in the errors object.

```
var arr = ["efirst", "esecond", "civil_no"];

$.each(arr, function(i, name) {
  if (xhr.responseJSON.errors.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    $("input[name='" + name + "']").addClass('errorClass').removeClass('border border-dark');      
  }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, it worked, i guess i will have to add remove class errorClass again, if response has value of that field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "some" function if you want a boolean result from comparing array.

Also you can use backtick for readability.

```
var arr = [ "efirst", "esecond", "civil_no"];

$.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function(key, value) {
    if(arr.some(val => val === key)){
       $( `input[name=${key}]`).removeClass('border border-dark');
       $( `input[name=${key}]` ).addClass('errorClass');
    }
 });
```

Read template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `some()` requires a function argument

Comment: Yeah that's better. Also think the `return` in `each` should be removed. A `return false` breaks out of the loop. Not sure what OP was expecting from that

Comment: One more problem is `value` is an array and the property name is `index`. `$.each(someObject, function(propertyName, value)...`

Comment: Right but `xhr.responseJSON.errors` looks to be an object. See my prior comment about `$.each` iterating objects and look at the image that shows value is array. The `arr` is holding the property names

Comment: @charlietfl okay instead of using value, i'll be using the key

Comment: Yes and also in the selector

Answer (score 1):

Change the "if" to

```
//if key is an element of arr
if (arr.indexOf(key) !== -1) {...}

//using es6 syntax
if (arr.includes(key)) {...}
```

And double `]]` without ending quote in `$( "input[name=" arr[i]])` is probably a typo.